# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, announcement

[Moderator election #9](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/9) on The Workplace has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: nvoigt]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/9) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5584993047805952).

Answer (score 16):

**Thank you for putting your trust in me!**

I will get to work and figure out what all the buttons do, while trying not to touch anything before I know what it does :)

Comment: Congratulations! Most of the buttons will warn you that you're about to do something irreversible... except for that one that you should never click... ;)

Comment: @ColleenV which button do you mea..#&$*#*$))... <404 not found>

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations @nvoigt! You are joining a good group of moderators!

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations @nvoigt!
I see that my jumping in helped accelerate this result.

To the CMs: Giving me a technical ban from the homepage of the site just for losing an election as predicted seems a little extreme:
[image]

Comment: A technical ban? Really?

Comment: Technical Ban? Care giving more details? Does the problem persist or perhaps it was your internet connection? Or perhaps a bug with election process if it persists... I see no bans on your user from your profile...

Comment: @DarkCygnus I read that as a joke based on the screenshot, not an actual complaint about a ban.

Comment: @ColleenV apparently I didn't :o)

Comment: Maybe the "something bad happened" is the election result! They are being kind to you.

Comment: That election result doesn't qualify as a bad thing happening. I can easily imagine insufficiently tested edge cases where server and user-side data disagree on a user's status as moderator, such as logged-in page reloads after election, so initially I thought it might mean the opposite (like Trump 2016, where even he & many protest voters expected Clinton to win). Fortunately, the meta link worked & had this post, changing the analogy to other countries where dissidents are more frequently jailed/exiled. Also, it took longer than expected, but access to the main site was eventually restored.